# How to check RTL-Language in WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

How can I check if the watch has an RTL-Language set? I tried the following but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
func alignmentOfLanguage() -> NSTextAlignment {
    if NSLocale.characterDirection(forLanguage: NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]) == .rightToLeft {
        return .right
    }
    return .left
}
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].